# Fix the position of widget in a row

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two widgets in my row, a text widget and a counter widget. The text widget contains value which increases and decreases when the counter is increased/decreased. Now, when the value increases, it pushes the counter towards the right. How do I prevent this from happening? I want the counter to stay in it's fixed position.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     var loyaltyPrice =  Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false).loyaltyPrice;
    return  
       Card(
        color:Colors.red[100],
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child:Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: [
                      Text('- \Tsh. $loyaltyPrice ',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red)),
                      SizedBox(width:120),
                     LoyaltyCounterView(),

                  ]),                 
                  ],
                )
              ),         
       );
        
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please share your UI Image.

Comment: Please see the screenshot. When the amount increases, the counter moves to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using sized box between your widget, wrap your text widget with container and set width for that

```
Row(
  children: [
       Container(width:your width,child:  Text('- \Tsh. $loyaltyPrice                   ',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red)),)
      LoyaltyCounterView(),

  ]),
```

and also another way is using `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` for your row widget.
I recommend using second way for solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

For your `Row`, add the argument `mainAxisAlignment`:

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

and remove the line:

```
SizedBox(width:120),
```

This will make the Text flushed left and the Counter widget flushed right. Other values to use are `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` and `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround`.

Comment: I would like to keep the sizedbox. I need the counter widget to be placed at that position. Is there another way of fixing the position of text widget?

Comment: Try putting `Text("your value", textAlign: TextAlign.left),`

Comment: this didn't work

Comment: @mcfred it seems like you're not following design standards. Like specifying position with fixed numbers. You're supposed to use flex widgets for that (Expanded, Flexible etc...)

I'm always able to solve any positioning issues by just following the standards.

And in your case, it would help if you show us your entire UI layout and what do you want to achieve, and why.

Comment: @mcfred Just to add to my comment. I only use fixed numbers with font sizes and icon sizes. For sizing and positioning other widgets, I use flex widgets.

Comment: @mcfred Can you show a screen shot of what you you got and another one of what you expect?

Comment: Please see the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

folow these steps:

1. delete **SizedBox(width:120),**
2. Put the text Widget of '- \Tsh. $loyaltyPrice ' inside a SizedBox
3. make sure that the width of the SizedBox is more than 120 based on that you want the empty space between the buttons and text is 120 and now the width of the SizedBox= the size of the text + 120

   ```
                 SizedBox(
                       child: Text(
                         '- \Tsh. $_counter ',
                         style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                       ),
                       width: 150,
                     ),
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget in your row

then use `Align` widget as child

Comment: This solution didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your counter in a Container with fixed width, in this way it will have the same space also with different number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

please add this changes to your code .

- add a fixed Height to your row (Because we want to use `expanded` in `column` )
- wrap your Text widget with `Expanded`
- wrap your Counter widget with `Expanded`

```
              SizedBox(
               height: 300 <- what you want
               child:Row(
                  children: [
                      Expanded(child:Text()),
                      SizedBox(width:120),
                     Expanded(child:LoyaltyCounterView()),

                  ]),                 
                ))
```